# Is Function object necessary

Tags: javascript, function, object

It is common and easy to create function like:

```
var f = function(){
    alert("something");
};
```

So why is there **Function object** like:

```
var f = new Function("alert('something');");
```

The latter is hard to write/read. I can only come up with one situation in which someone typing some JS code to the webpage and running it. This can also be solved with `eval`.

Why Function object?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `Function` object can be used to dynamically generate functions.

```
var some_fixed_value = 1;
var f = new Function("return " + some_fixed_value);
```

Opposed to:

```
var some_fixed_value = 1;
var f = function() {
    return some_fixed_value;
};
// Break the function logic:
some_fixed_value = 'not_fixed_any_more!';
```

or, using two function expressions:

```
var f = (function(copy_of_fixed_value) {
    return function() {
        return copy_of_fixed_value;
    };
})(some_fixed_value);
```

"This can also be solved with `eval`":

```
var func_func = new Function('x', 'return x');  //function anonymous(x){return x}
var evil_func = eval('function(x){return x}');  //SyntaxError: function statement
                                                // requires a name
var eval_func = eval('(function(x){return x})');//function(x){return x}
```

Comment: `function factory(ret){ return function(){return ret;};};`

Comment: @onemach That incorporates another function expression. What's the point of your question?

Comment: You can do the same with closures.

Comment: Can you please link any TypeScript documentation you referred to for this response?

Answer (score 4):

The Function (with capital F) is not a keyword, it's a base class for any other functions in JavaScript, given the fact that *everything* in JavaScript is an object, functions should/must inherit from a base class that represents base functionality of all other functions (methods/classes).

You can play a lot with function inheritance via Function's prototype:

here's an example to define a .run method for all functions in JS:

```
Function.prototype.run = function (delay) {
    setTimeout(this, delay);
};
```

test:

```
function test(){console.log("test")};
test.run(2000);
```

there's an undocumented `__proto__` property that points to the base-class prototype, you can check it on each instance of function:

```
test.__proto__ == Function.prototype; // true
```

Comment: Exactly! Most builtin constructors (like `String`, `Array`, `Function`) are not intended to be called, but rather to be extended.