# Can Type Script interface extend the Function

Tags: angular, typescript

Learning Angular I came across the following declaration:

```
interface IMessagesOperation extends Function {
(messages: Message[]): Message[];
}
```

What exactly does this mean (why `Function` has capital "F" instead of just being `function`). How do I implement the concrete class in this case. I have never seen that before - I am coming from Java world.

Comment: Read about hybrid types https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#hybrid-types

Comment: Thanks, but what is `Function` with capital "F".

Comment: The Function object can be used to dynamically generate functions.

see https://stackoverflow.com/a/9749553/12002831

Comment: I can't compile this code:                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                  
     `Function.prototype.run = function (delay) {
    setTimeout(this, delay);
    };   `                                                      
in my angular project. What in this example `this` refers to? Why `run` is displayed by my Visual Studio Code as `undefined` ? Can somebody please help me

Comment: @JanuszDalecki - (Where did that come from? It seems unrelated to the question.) That's JavaScript code (and not really ideal JavaScript code), [here's how you'd do it in TypeScript](https://tsplay.dev/WzAY1m) and doing it a bit more properly (even in the JavaScript sense).

Comment: It comes from the article I was referred to [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749546/is-function-object-necessary/9749553#9749553)

Comment: [@T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder)    Same problem. Visual Studio Code complains in the code   :   `Function.prototype.run...` that `Property 'run' does not exist on type 'Function'.`

Comment: @T.J. Crowder. Could you please help with your code:                                                                          
   `Function.prototype.run = function (delay: number) {
      setTimeout(this, delay);
    };`                                                                                                                                                        The compilation error says: `Property 'run' does not exist on type 'Function'` inside my Angular test component. It is in .ts file. If I put it in the .js file it works fine.

Comment: @JanuszDalecki - It isn't my code (it's not clear to me where that code came from, it just appeared in [your comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71598343/can-type-script-interface-extend-the-function?noredirect=1#comment126567136_71598343)). I did show you how to do this in TypeScript [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71598343/can-type-script-interface-extend-the-function?noredirect=1#comment126567446_71598343), with clear notes.

Comment: OK. Thanks for your overall help. It was great. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be some specific idiomatic reason for it that I haven't heard of, but basically that's saying: `IMessagesOperation` is a function that has all the usual `Function` stuff and accepts an array of `Message` and returns an array of `Message`, like this:

```typescript
type IMessagesOperation = (messages: Message[]) => Message[];
```

It's not clear to me why they didn't write it that way, other than that interfaces can be augmented by other declarations (see [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#differences-between-type-aliases-and-interfaces) and [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces)). Or perhaps something to do with [how conflicts are resolved](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#interfaces-vs-intersections) in type aliases (`type`) with `&` vs. `interface` with `extends`.

To give you an idea what I mean by "augmented by other declarations," with an interface it's possible to do this elsewhere in the code:

```
interface IMessagesOperation {
    (messages: string): Message[];
    //         ^^^^^^−−−−−− note the change
}
```

That gets merged with the interface in your question, producing a function overload type where both of these calls are valid:

```
const op: IMessagesOperation = /*...*/;
const messages1 = op("testing");
const messages2 = op(messages);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIQM4bgcxQbwChkTlIAPMALmQzClBwG5CBfQ0SWRFdLXCAGEA9uDihoyIqWQBbTNjwYafRRADaAXRbsO4aPCTIAkqoEYA8gAdocMMFHIIlCCAAmGZADEAriAT2jtKkABTy-EoqCgJaAJRRERrabIR6XIYoptFK1raBIFLEoeFqyrT0jPFo2Uk6qW4QCAA2cFAoCKJ0yMJWNFmJljZQdg4gLIQdIF0l5glqWsgAvMjq+BTUyABEABbAm6zJE51gcjUYAIxL3VYhm5B0jJuxLJPTZwBMVz1hZ8+EQA)

You can't do that with the type alias (`type IMessagesOperation = (messages: Message[]) => Message[];`).

> why `Function` has capital "F" instead of just being `function`

It's referring to JavaScript's [`Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) constructor, although in that specific case (because it's a type context, not a value [runtime] context) it's referring to the type of thing the `Function` constructor creates: a function.

> How do I implement the concrete class in this case.

It's a function, not a class, so you'd write a function:

```typescript
const m1: IMessagesOperation = function(messages: Message[]): Message[] {
    return messages;
};
```

[Typescript playground example of the above](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIQM4bgcxQbwChkTkAPALmQzClBwG5CBfQwgeneQBUALFUJFiIUATwD2AV2q9xAdwgATQoOjwkyAJLosuTAHkADtDhhg4kMghlIIRRmQAxSSARmLyIqWQAKALaY2HgYVDpBEADaALoAlKGBetFMrBxcAKJYEODAcAA2uaLIYPzUcAGEYKLGWmF6GEYm7iAATMgAvL4BusHx3ZGx7QB8aAl4SWycyADqdGYgOMgWEIQIFjTIfgCMVNqjBsZQpuaWHTAubsf+eyEjfdFxt+HRnsSkUBBgklCWXeEYyUxUjx+KIAOTvZBwLDAHAgALgAC0qz8hiOACNcstViB1ls4DtasEGocmq0OltAZM+MAHIpxJgQKCwBtTAheEUSu8AI6SYDveFgBziGAcgTgNQiFZrZl+ZoE67Eo4eU7nJo+GKeZCTNJQKDiKCQ2mYPlKV4kd6fb4AwhAA)

Comment: Is it needed though. I have removed it from my definition of  `IMessagesOperation ` and the code works just fine.

Comment: @JanuszDalecki - As I say above, the only reason I can think of for using `interface` for this is that it can be augmented by other declarations. I've added an example. Even if they don't do that with that particular interface, they might make a habit of using that form so they *can* do it without having to go back and change it from a type alias to an interface.

Comment: @[t-j-crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder)                                 
I would like insert my code into Typescript playground link like you did. Could you please point me to some instructions how to do that?

Comment: @JanuszDalecki - Go to https://www.typescriptlang.org/play then, when you want to share the copy, click the **Share** button. That will update the URL of hte page to include the code (in compressed form). Then you can share that URL. If it's long (and they do tend to be long) you can use https://tsplay.dev/ to shorten it.